# c++ getopt and optarg can't take in multiple input

Tags: c++, getopt

i am trying to write a program which will take in multiple input and this is my code

```
int main (int argc,char *argv[])
  {
    char tmp;
   
    while((tmp=getopt(argc,argv,"e:d"))!=-1)
    {
      switch(tmp)
      {
        
        case 'e':   
        cout<<"Your name is "<< optarg <<endl;
          break;
       
        case 'd':
          cout<<"Your password is "<< optarg <<endl;
          break;
       
        default:
          cout << "to be done later" << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

i tried to run this program like this

> a -e first second

and the result i get is

> Your name is first

is it possible to make it such that i can get the following output without using -e twice?

> your name is first
>
> your name is second

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `a -e first -e second`?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the program using `a -e first -e second`.

Comment: thx for the help! but is it possible to run it without using -e twice?

Comment: You can pass `first second` as  a single argument to the program. For this, it is usually surrounded by quotes: `a -e "first second"`, the details depend on the shell from which you are starting the program.